# Starting Nokia application for s60 v5

Tags: symbian

I want to create a simple application for Nokia 5230 (s60 v5).
Application will given some hardcoded numbers and it will accept calls from these no.s as soon as call will received.

How can i start developing application for Nokia?
Will WRT 1.0 will work for these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRT probably can't do what you're asking. [Forum Nokia](http://forum.nokia.com/) has all the answers.